# pointerIndex out of Range multitouch

Tags: android, multi-touch, outofrangeexception

At first, i really know there are more than one post about it, but non helped me fixing the bug/misstake. I am sorry if its a repost and hope you guys can help me getting rid of this bug.

```
11-28 17:36:36.110: W/dalvikvm(8380): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a331f8)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1974)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.main.TouchEventControler.processJoyPadTouchRelease(TouchEventControler.java:194)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.main.TouchEventControler.processRelease(TouchEventControler.java:237)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.main.TouchEventControler.processTouchEvent(TouchEventControler.java:88)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.main.GameField.onTouchEvent(GameField.java:142)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5546)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1938)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1375)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1886)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5726)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-28 17:36:36.110: E/AndroidRuntime(8380):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do handle them like this and i am happy that it sometimes runs like i want it if it dont crash by that error:

```
public void processTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // create an action
    int action = (event.getActionMasked() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);
    // getting pointerindex
    int pointerIndex = ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT);
    // getting pointer id

    //catch invalide
    if(pointerIndex == MotionEvent.INVALID_POINTER_ID){
        return;
    }

    int pointerId = event.findPointerIndex(pointerIndex);
    // switch case for the action
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // if action down
        processHitButtonTouch(event, pointerId);
        processJoyPadTouch(event, pointerId);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // if pointer down (second
                                            // finger/third)
        processHitButtonTouch(event, pointerId);
        processJoyPadTouch(event, pointerId);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // if action up
        processRelease(event, pointerId);
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // if action up second/third finger
        processRelease(event, pointerId);
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

In the methodes i call in that switch i just get the position of the touch and handle them. I just could put a getX(pointerIndex) in a try catch and return if its a error. But isnt there a better way?!

Thanks alot for all that help i already got.

Asked for:

```
    public void processJoyPadTouchRelease(MotionEvent event, int pointerId) {
    int touchPosX = (int) event.getX(pointerId);
    int touchPosY = (int) event.getY(pointerId);

    if (( //dont freak out here! it's just looking for if the
            //touch was inside the Joypad! Nothing more!!
            //it's in breckets!
            touchPosX > 2 * Config.BLOCKSIZE
            && touchPosX < 4 * Config.BLOCKSIZE
            && touchPosY > 3 * Config.BLOCKSIZE
            && touchPosY < 5 * Config.BLOCKSIZE
            // touch up event handled
            || 2 * Config.BLOCKSIZE < touchPosX
            && touchPosX < (Config.BLOCKSIZE * 4)
            && touchPosY > (7 * Config.BLOCKSIZE)
            && touchPosY < (9 * Config.BLOCKSIZE)
            // touch down handled
            || (touchPosX < 2 * Config.BLOCKSIZE
            && touchPosY > (5 * Config.BLOCKSIZE) 
            && touchPosY < (7 * Config.BLOCKSIZE))
            // touch left handled
            || (4 * Config.BLOCKSIZE < touchPosX
            && touchPosX < (Config.BLOCKSIZE * 6)
            && touchPosY > (5 * Config.BLOCKSIZE) 
            && touchPosY < 7 * Config.BLOCKSIZE)) 
            //touch right handled

            //and the char isnt idle (so it's moving)
        && charac.getStatus() != Status.IDLE)
    //THAN do =>>
    {
        charac.setStatus(Status.IDLE);
        joyPad.status = Status.IDLE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could compare it to the size() of whatever is throwing the error and make sure its not too big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to make sure that `pointerIndex < event.getPointerCount();`

But i think that maybe you have a misunderstanding here. The pointerIndex in your code is the index of the pointer that changed, it should only be used in ACTION_POINTER_DOWN and ACTION_POINTER_UP. If you only have one finger on the screen, the pointerIndex is invalid here.

Comment: well it actually works with 2 fingers but sometimes it crashes with that code. But it only does this if i touch really fast. I added a if for the case you said.

Comment: I added the code. It should normaly work because you can get the first touch event also via its ID. tryed it with logcat

Comment: oh my goodness sorry for that didnt see that misstake Thanks alot for that bugfixing!